# Best and most secure way to store data in SQLite on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

This is more of a design question than anything else.

I have an app that I am starting to migrate to have an offline mode. I am using SQLite with GRDB wrapper. Each time a user authenticates I download a set of user profile data i.e. user ID, date added, access level, profile image url, settings etc. I then store this information in to a local SQLite table which matches the structure of the MYSQL online version.

I am also storing an auth token and password in the keychain and using these for all communications to the server (no user ID) after authentication.

My question is, once a user logs out should I drop the existing tables in SQLite therefore clearing all previous users data and start clean for the current user?

My concern is about the security of the information from the previous user being available if say, user1 logged in to the app on a friends phone. Without clearing the information upon log out would this data be available to the new user? Obviously not through the app itself but through some other form of view the SQLite information.

All sensitive information i.e. passwords etc are stored in keychain.

I realise this could be an opinion base question but thats what I am looking for, just some opinions on what you think COULD work best.

Thanks

Comment: Besides my answer below, I have something else to ask: why letting the user log out, in the first place? So many apps let the user log in, and that's it. People never log in the Facebook app of their friend's iPhone, do they?

Comment: I think you are right for the most part of logging out however I think I just want to cover all possible scenarios where some information i.e. Profile image, name, email, account type etc could be removed from the app simply by logging out. All apps do allow a logout but yes, I would never log in to specific apps on friends phones. The amount of data downloaded during login is fairly small so thats why I was thinking of basically dropping all user specific tables (user, settings, activities etc) from the phone and creating new ones upon login but keep the generic ones (news etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iPhone is given or lent with all apps installed, the new owner may well be able to read the database filled with the previous owner's information. It's like lending your mac filled with your emails. So you may well have to reset the database when the user logs out, if it may contain sensitive information (and as soon as the user can write text or take pictures, it is potentially sensitive information). I have already written a chat app that does exactly that. Besides, thanks for using GRDB ;-)

Comment: No problem, GRDB is great and really easy to use!